# In-page analytics (Google Analytics) not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

In-page analytics (Google Analytics) not working. I tried few ways how to make In-page analytics work but none of them helped.

I did "Load unsafe scripts" from shield icon in Chrome.

I also tried

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

And I closed all Chrome instances and checked in Task Manager before I run it with disabled security.

I also tried old Firefox (versions 4, 12, 26).

None of that worked, I still can not use In-page Analytics and all I got was this lousy error message:

```
Problem loading In-Page Analytics

We tried looking for a few common problems with your setup, but couldn't find what's wrong. Please try again later.

Oh! If you are using Chrome or Firefox browser, it may be an issue with a recent change in the default security mode of those browsers. Those browsers now implement a security policy that prevents insecure content from being displayed within a secure page. You can work around this by clicking the shield icon at the address bar, and allowing insecure content, or you can use the full-view option.

You can try the Page Analytics Chrome Extension which has almost identical functionality to the In-Page Analytics report, but can often resolve these issues.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually the two possible solutions are right there: Either use full view (you can permanently enable it in the property settings), which (at least for me) works in Chrome. Or use the Page Analytics Chrome Extension, which is rather good. I doubt that Google will fix inline In-page Analytics since it's not very useful in the first place, and frankly I'd recommend you get a third party heatmap/clickmap software.

Comment: Oh, for some reason "Full view" is working now... It did not work before. I want "Browser Size", not click map.

Comment: One website works in "Full view", other does not. There is no error message, not even in Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the 'Page Analytics' Chrome extension; it's not nearly as buggy.

Comment: Does not have "Browser Size" function.

Comment: You can use the Chrome developer tools to emulate different browser sizes

Comment: "Browser Size" function does not emulate different browser size. It tells what viewport size visitors have https://analytics.googleblog.com/2012/06/new-feature-conduct-browser-size.html